Having issues with drizzle-kit and postgress push command
I'm using drizzle ORM and supabase to manage database but I am facing some issues when running yarn push here is the error code
`Pulling schema from database...
PostgresError: Tenant or user not found
    at ErrorResponse (C:\Users\[userName]\Downloads\sendtype\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:79677:27)
    at handle (C:\Users\[userName]\Downloads\sendtype\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:79454:7)
    at Socket.data (C:\Users\[userName]\Downloads\sendtype\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:79277:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
    at TCP.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  severity_local: 'FATAL',
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: 'XX000'
}`

The drizzle.config.ts file
`import {defineConfig} from 'drizzle-kit'
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config({path: '.env.local'})

if (!process.env.DATABASE_URL) {
  console.log(' Cannot find database url')
}

export default defineConfig({
  schema: './src/lib/supabase/schema.ts',
  out: './migrations',
  dialect: 'postgresql',
  dbCredentials: {
    url: process.env.DATABASE_URL || '',
    database: 'postgres',
    port: Number(process.env.DATABASE_PORT),
    host: 'aws-0-us-east-1.pooler.supabase.com',
    user: 'postgres.user',
    password: process.env.PW || '',
  },
})
`

The error occurs when I run yarn push, to migrate the changes to supabase
here is the package.json file
` "push": "drizzle-kit push",
    "pull": "drizzle-kit introspect",
    "generate": "drizzle-kit generate",
    "drop": "drizzle-kit drop",
    "check": "drizzle-kit check",
    "up": "drizzle-kit up"`

when I run yarn generate the returning message is No schema changes, nothing to migrate

Did you verify if DATABASE_URL is correct?
Also supabase gives you a complete URL to copy besides for the password which you might need to regenerate and then it's a bit simpler to have dbCredentials: { url: env.DATABASE_URL }
